# certbot giving error DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, lets-encrypt, certbot

**problem statement** 
I am in the process to create a certificate for my domain with the help of certbot. same procedure I tried for other environments, from the same machine, and for the same domain. but today I am unable to create a certificate.

**steps  taken (same steps I took for other environments in past for same domain and it works fine)**

please note **my domain** is registered domain nameAzurezure

```
certbot -d api.stg.<my domain> --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

this command provide me text record. this txt record i added in my AZure DNS zone with key  **_acme-challenge.api.stg**

when I click enter I get the following error

```
Failed authorization procedure. api.stg.<my domain> (dns-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for api.stg.<my domain>

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: api.stg.<my domain>
   Type:   None
   Detail: DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for
   api.stg.<my domain>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create CAA dns record for Azure DNS hosted (or any other) domain zones for lets encrypt to work. Here's example powershell (cannot be done in portal as of now):

```
New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name @ -ResourceGroupName %rg% -ZoneName %zone% -Ttl 3600 -RecordType CAA `
  -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -Caaflags 0 -CaaTag "issue" -CaaValue "letsencrypt.org")
```